# Show that $ SL(2,5) $ has no subgroup isomorphic to $ A_5 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, simple-groups

I'm trying to show that there's no subgroup of $ SL(2,5) $ isomorphic to $ A_5 $. I've already shown that $ A_5 $ is simple, and my strategy is to show that $ SL(2,5) $ contains no simple subgroups of order 60. My problem is that unfortunately I can't use Sylow theorems, which would make this a lot easier. Would anybody have any helpful tips/hints on how to start this WITHOUT Sylow theorems? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$SL(2,5)$ has only one element of order $2$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_special_linear_group:SL(2,5)) (which is $-I_2$), whereas [$A_5$ has $15$ such elements](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_alternating_group:A5) (each being the product of two disjoints transpositions).

Comment: My bad, it is precisely $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ which is the (unique) element of order $2$.